# Force json_encode to return array instead objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've been wondering if it's possible to force `json_encode` into returning `Array` instead an `Object` while still keeping the "integer" index.

What am I trying to achieve if you're asking is an array of usernames ( with their userID's as keys in the array ).

So if I have a list of mutual friends like this in PHP:

```
1 => 'John Doe',
2 => 'Jane Doe',
5 => 'Oliver Natefield',
11 => 'Chris Cole'
```

I'd like to use `json_encode` and I tried two methods.

First one is by simply adding into an empty PHP Array, values to their respective index ( userID ).

```
<?php
    $list = array( );

    foreach ( $friends as $userID => $name )
        $list[ $userID ] = $name;

    echo json_encode( $list );
?>
```

That creates me an `Object` sadly. Ok, then I tried something else...

```
<?php
    $list = array( );

    foreach ( $users as $userID => $name )
        array_splice( $list, $userID, 0, $name );

    echo json_encode( $list );
?>
```

Again, failed, this time, it's an `Array`, but the `indexes` are not taken into consideration.

I know that.. the array should be like :

```
undefined, // userID 0
'John Doe', // userID 1
'Jane Doe', // userID 2
undefined, // userID 3
undefined,  // userID 4
'Oliver Natefield', // userID 5
undefined, //userID 6
undefined, // etc
```

But... if I have a friend with `userID` with the index `1504` .. shouldn't there be a memory downside ?

And while we're at it, can I see how much memory does an array of `1000` undefined elements use ? It's relevant because if it consumes too much memory, I'll just have to search through an array of objects for a `username` after a specific `userID`.

Comment: why you need json list instead of json object?

Comment: this list that you have.. it looks like a PHP array. Is that what it is? You are calling it "list", just be specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really possible. It's a restriction of Javascript syntax, which is basically what JSON is. You can't specify array keys in a Javascript "shortcut" array definition, like you can with PHP. e.g.

```
$foo = array(1 => 'a', 10 => 'b');
```

There's no such notation in JS, the only shortcut allowed is

```
foo = ['a', 'b'];
```

which would give you the PHP equivalent `0 => 'a', 1 => 'b'`. To use non-sequential array keys, you **MUST** use an Object:

```
foo = {1: 'a', 10: 'b'};
```

Comment: Yes.. I knew that but still there was hope ! 

Thanks anyway !